# Better resolution of my raster

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, virtual-raster

if I am merging my raster files or if I am creating a virtual raster, the quality is not as good, as the input rasters on their own. Before:
[image]

As a virtual raster:
[image]

Does somebody know any tips or tricks to maintain the quality ?

Comment: You can set the output resolution to highest in QGIS which may help you. Have you actually compared the cell size for before and after? What you may find is they are in fact the same resolution but the image may "look" hazy because the image stretch is now applied across the entire image.

Comment: Hi, I already set the output resolution to highest and the cell size is the same.  what do you mean with image stretch? So you mean it is just visually and if I want to proceed the results with the virtual raster should be the same ?

Comment: Okay well yes I believe that if the cell size is the same then all should be good. Can you see how in your virtual raster areas that were lighter in your tiles now seem darker? In other words QGIS is applying a stretch that is purely visual across the entire image. Now depending on what your are doing the results will not be exactly the same because when creating a virtual raster an interpolation is applied which can change some raster values but this should be negligible across the entire image. Have a look and compare cell values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No worries at all. Please let me know if the above has answered your question so I can format it into an appropriate answer?

Comment: yes, I think that was the answer I was looking for. Again, thank you

Comment: my pleasure. Would you be able to accept my answer below to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summarising my comments above:**

Firstly check that the output resolution was set to highest and that the virtual raster cell size is the same as those in the merged image which I believe it was in your case.

To add to this, if all of your raster files you are combining are the same resolution then the output resolution to anything will return the same resolution virtual raster. I believe that:

- Average = the average pixel size of all raster inputs
- Highest = the highest resolution pixel size of all raster inputs
- Lowest = the lowest resolution pixel size of all raster inputs

If this is true then what you will actually find is that the virtual raster is not of lower resolution, but it may look that way because of the colour stretch that has been applied to the entire image. Put simply, in one of your tiled images the range of cell values will most likely be smaller than the range in cell values across all of them together in a virtual raster. This means that the contrast between features that are close together is lower but the cell values should actually be the same.

**A small caveat:**

When creating a virtual raster, an interpolation is applied which will only affect cell values if the raster resolution varies between each input raster or if the cells do not align in a grid with one another.